# How to change android studio svn path in build.gradle

Tags: macos, android-studio, svn

In build.gradle our team use following code go get svn revision:

```
def getSvnRevision() {
new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
    def result = exec {
        executable = 'svn'
        args = ['info']
        standardOutput = os
    }
    def outputAsString = os.toString()
    def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev: (\d+)/
    ext.svnRev = "${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}".toInteger()
    }
    return svnRev
}
```

Works under windows.

But under my mac, it fails as 'svn' point to '/usr/bin/svn' which is 1.7 and my workspace use /usr/local/bin/svn(1.8).

Have try to set preferences -> Version control ->Subversion->Use command line client to /usr/local/bin/svn, but seems gradle insist to use /usr/bin/svn.

Examine by:

```
def getSvnRevision() {
    new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
        def result = exec {
            executable = 'which'
            args = ['svn']
            standardOutput = os
        }
        def outputAsString = os.toString()
        print 'svn:'+outputAsString
//        def matchLastChangedRev = outputAsString =~ /Last Changed Rev: (\d+)/
//
//        ext.svnRev = "${matchLastChangedRev[0][1]}".toInteger()
    }
return 1
//    return svnRev
}
```

output:
svn: /usr/bin/svn

So, how can I changed svn point to /usr/local/bin/svn without changed getSvnRevision? (Because getSvnRevision works fine on other team memebers' computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that providing full path in `executable` should work:

`executable = '/usr/local/bin/svn'`

Comment: yes, it should work. But other team members are using windows os that would not live with this edit.

Comment: finnaly i add: import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
ext{
    svn = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC) ? '/usr/local/bin/svn' : 'svn'
}